# C++ Copy map into another with same and/or different keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I'm trying to make a simulation of different populations with each multiple genotypes. Each population has a map (mOccurrences) with key = genotype and value = number of individuals with that genotype. 
These populations should migrate and when individuals go into another niche, the niche's map should be updated to reflect the genomic distribution of the new population. 
As such, once I've made my individuals migrate, I try to update mOccurences; now some of the incoming genes can be the same as the current ones in the populations, so they should only be added, while other can be new so they should be created inside the map. 
I have tried to iterate over the incomers' map and then use:

mOccurrences.[New->first] += New->second;

but for some reason, it only adds the non-existing genotypes and for the ones common to both populations, the number of individuals does not change.

I have also tried the find method and the insert but to no avail...

```
void Population::addOccurrences( std::map<Allele, size_t> immigrants ) {

std::cout<< "Size NICHE Initiale " << mSize << std::endl; //shows size before immigrants
mSize = 0; //number of individuals in the niche in total must be updates 
std::map<Allele, size_t>::iterator New; 
std::map<Allele, size_t>::iterator it; 

std::cout << "Occurrences initial" << std::endl;  //PRINTINT current distribution to check
for(it = mOccurrences.begin(); it!= mOccurrences.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << std::endl; 

}

std::cout << "IMMIGRANT" << std::endl; 
for(New = immigrants.begin(), it = mOccurrences.begin(); New != immigrants.end(); ++New, ++it) 
{ 
    std::cout << New->first << '\t' << New->second << std::endl; //PRINTING Immigrants genotype distribution

    it = mOccurrences.find(New->first); 
    if(it != mOccurrences.end()) {
    it->second += New->second;  //if the allele is already present in population, only add individuals
    } else { 
        mOccurences.insert(New); //else, insert the pair
    }
}

std::cout << "Occurrences final" << std::endl; //PRINTING distribution after migration
for(it = mOccurrences.begin(); it!= mOccurrences.end(); ++it) {
    mSize+= it->second; 
    std::cout << it->first << '\t' << it->second << std::endl; 

}

}
```

Comment: Can you provide Allele implementation?

Comment: Your code is a mess, can you describe what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess, and would not even compile. ( for example `mOccurences.insert(New);` is invalid). Looks like you just need this:

```
void Population::addOccurrences( std::map<Allele, size_t> immigrants )
{
     for( std::map<Allele, size_t>::const_iterator it = immigrants.begin(); it!= immigrants.end(); ++it)
        mOccurrences[ it->first ] += it->second;
}
```

Note: you should change parameter type to const reference, there is no reason to copy it by value and that could be expensive. And if you can use C++11:

```
void Population::addOccurrences( const std::map<Allele, size_t> &immigrants )
{
     for( const auto &im : immigrants )
        mOccurrences[ im.first ] += im.second;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I realised afterwards, I've been trying out so many things it all got messed up.
I've tried the C++11 solution you've proposed and it doesn't work either. I've printed all occurrences and either not all keys were not added and values didnt change.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution !

```
void Population::addOccurrences( std::map<Allele, size_t> immigrants ) {

mSize = 0; //number of individuals in the niche in total must be updates 
std::map<Allele, size_t>::iterator New; 
std::map<Allele, size_t>::iterator it; 

for(it = mOccurrences.begin(); it != mOccurrences.end(); ++it) {

    Allele temp = it->first; 
    for(New = immigrants.begin(); New != immigrants.end(); ++New) {
        if(temp == New->first) { 
            it->second += New->second; 
            immigrants.erase(New); 
        }
    }
}
mOccurrences.insert(immigrants.begin(), immigrants.end()); 

for(it = mOccurrences.begin(); it!= mOccurrences.end(); ++it) {

    mSize+= it->second; 
}


}
```